# How to increase the length of Y-axis values on Plotly chart?

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, plotly.js

I am trying to implement a Plotly horizontal bar chart in ReactJS.
Below is the code. On Y axis I have text of length 44 (giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes).
On chart I am able to see only 14 chars. How to increase the length here to see all chars on chart?

```
var trace1 = {
  y: ['giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  name: 'SF Zoo',
  orientation: 'h',
  type: 'bar'
};

var trace2 = {
  y: ['giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  x: [12, 18, 29],
  name: 'LA Zoo',
  orientation: 'h',
  type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {barmode: 'stack'};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Chart that I am getting.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `layout.yaxis.automargin` to `true` or `"left"`, see the documentation on [yaxis.automargin](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-automargin).

```js
var trace1 = {
    y: ['giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    x: [20, 14, 23],
    name: 'SF Zoo',
    orientation: 'h',
    type: 'bar'
};

var trace2 = {
    y: ['giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes_giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    x: [12, 18, 29],
    name: 'LA Zoo',
    orientation: 'h',
    type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
    barmode: 'stack',
    yaxis: {automargin: true},
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.18.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
</style>


<body>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:600px;height:250px;border:1px solid gray"></div>

</body>
```